# How to set the cache time in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, ehcache

[image]I used the springboot to send the verification code. The valid time for setting the verification code was two minutes, and it will expire in two minutes later. Can I do this by setting up the cache? Or other ways. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redis for this purpose.

Redis is an open source in-memory data structure store that can be used as a cache. It provides a way to add expiry time to your keys. After the expiry time, keys will be invalidated/removed from Redis automatically.

In your maven, give the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In your SpringBoot application, you need to define just following properties:

```
spring.redis.host=
spring.redis.port=
```

And you can set the expiry time like:

```
public void put(final T key, final T hashKey, final Object value, final long exiryInMilliseconds) {
        hashOps.put(key, hashKey, value);
        if (exiryInMilliseconds > 0) {
            redisTemplate.expire(key, exiryInMilliseconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }

    }
```

Both RedisTemplate & HashOperations are provided by Redis core package. You can either inject them using Spring like these or use them by creating instances yourself.

```
@Resource
private RedisTemplate<T, T> redisTemplate;

@Resource(name = "redisTemplate")
private  <T, T, Object> hashOps;
```

At the time of retrieval, if you do this:

```
hashOps.get(key, hashKey);
```

it will return **null** if expiry time has elapsed / or key does not exist. else you will get your object.

Comment: Sorry for not replying in time, I was busy with other matters during this period. When I added dependency "spring-boot-starter-data-redis", there was A problem. The "redis jar" is downloaded but it didn't work properly.Take a look at my updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ehcache3, it was designed for such use cases !

Have a look at the documentation, in particular, [the part about expiry](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/expiry.html).

Then, hack your project together, there are many ehcache3 + spring boot examples out [there](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/examples.html#xml-with-107-extension), [there](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/tree/master/fullstack), and [there](https://github.com/anthonydahanne/ehcache3-disk-persistence-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/ehcache.xml), with the added benefit that you can just rely on the [Java EE official caching spec, JSR-107](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107), and not be vendor dependent.